# Force subclasses to set a inner class in java

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, abstract

I'm developing an app that requires the use of Bluetooth. The issue is that I have several activities that use the Bluetooth communication and I'm creating a class that makes the communication. For that, I need to resend the result to the activity.
I'm trying to implement the activity like this:

```
    public abstract class MyCommunicationActivity extends Activity {
    public static class MYHANDLER extends Handler{};
}
```

I want to to force every activity to create a HANDLER that handles the response from the communication class and this class will receive an object MyCommunication class so it knows that the activity will wave a subclass that is a handler to handle the result.
I've did it like this, but my sub classes (those that extend MyCommunicationActivity) aren't being force to implement the handler.

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: Have an abstract method `getHandler()` then that can return a static member variable from the sub classes.

Comment: There is better solution I think. Please implement handler as class in different file and construct it using Handler(Activity) to get access to public fields in your activity. This is some kind of composition pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a method like this:

```
public abstract Handler getHandler();
```

This will force all subclasses to implement `getHandler()` and return a Handler there.

Answer (score 0):

Make the inner class abstract by adding an abstract member to it.

```
public abstract class MyCommunicationActivity extends Activity {
  public static class MYHANDLER extends Handler {
    public abstract void handle();
  }
}
```

Comment: This wont compile, as "MYHANDLER" isn't abstract, and therefore can't have abstract methods.